# Using SELECT * FROM table

Tags: mysql, sql

I understand that using a SELECT * FROM table is considered a bad practice. One reason behind this is that you are select ALL columns from the table , and in case a the table is modified in future and there are extra columns added, you will be fetching those too, and perhaps will not need those.

Assuming that at the time of writing the SELECT * , first time, there indeed was a need to select all columns.

My Question is : Is there any other reason why it might be a bad practice ?

Comment: Sometimes the _order_ of columns returned matters, and that is specified in the `SELECT` list. That's particularly true if you are using an API that doesn't provide the ability to retrieve columns by name and instead requires you to know their positions.

Comment: It's clearer what you are fetching (and you know field names immediately) from the database, `*` is ambiguous.

Comment: how about plain efficiency? what's the point of pulling down the binary blob cv of all users when you just want their names and emails?

select what you need when you need it

Comment: Few reasons here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031145/sql-server-wildcard

Comment: When writing code, there are sorts of places for shortcuts and being implicit rather than explicit, but SQL queries are IMHO _not_ the place for that. SQL is one place where premature optimization is often, well, timely and not premature.

Comment: [This article is probably worth a read](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). It is directed at SQL Server but most of the arguments apply to all DBMS.

Comment: If you have any inner joins you are definitely returning duplicate data you don't need because the data in the join columns is the same. This is a waste of network and database resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that comes to my mind is the projection [the Wikipedia covers that part pretty nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29). And in [DBA website](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12619/what-does-the-term-projection-refer-to-in-an-sql-query-or-view-definition) you have a nice question about it.

You not only miss control over the columns you will present, you also miss the control over the order of the columns. By specifying them you get to have the full control over the resultset + you optimize its size by the elements you really need.

To answer your question, you also miss the possibility to control the location of each column.

```
SELECT * FROM table; # it would depend of the table internal order
['Surname','Office','Name','Irrelevant']

SELECT Name,Surname,Office FROM table; # you decide which column to show the element
['Name','Surname','Office']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another reason could be the bandwith consumed : if you only need one or two informations, it is useless to get all the informations.
The application which receives the data is also slower because it has to get a large amount of data whereas it only need a few.